# In Terminator Salvation how did the machines get the Endoskeleton into Marcus?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-salvation

In *Terminator Salvation*, we are introduced to Marcus, who becomes a completely different type of machine.

[In a teaser trailer for T2](http://www.jamescamerononline.com/T2FAQ.htm), The T-800 was said to have living tissue grown around the endoskeleton:

> The teaser trailer for T2, directed by Stan Winston for $150,000 shows
>   the entire procedure of how a T-800 comes off an assembly line and
>   **gets his flesh grown around the endoskeleton.**

But, when looking at Marcus when he is on the table, he does not seem to have any visible scars that would indicate that they did not cut him open and put in the endoskeleton that way. (*I say indicate at this point of the question*)

[image]

In the scene where he was just blown up and he has pieces of flesh missing everywhere, you can clearly see the metal endoskeleton:

[image]

Then there is the last scenes where they fix him up and again he seems to have no scars showing:

[image]

Which would mean they have some regenerating process that enable the machines to heal Marcus.

Did they replicate him and grow the flesh around the endoskeleton like they did with the T-800? Or was it surgically inserted and then have all the body tissue that was cut open healed using the regenerating technology? Or did they do something else?

Is there any canon information as to how they built Marcus?

Comment: One of [these](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/abbeyhorncouk/i/pzi/shoehorn_oxhorn_with_stag_antler_handle_shc.jpg?_t=1512815924) and some of [this](http://d2arxepu0ul4m5.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/06133724/leadimage.jpg)

Comment: @Valorum, that is an answer right there!!!LOL

Comment: IIRC Marcus' heart was still inside, as was probably his brain. Therefore, the correct question would be "How did the machines get Marcus into the exoskeleton?" (and grow the artificial skin afterwards)

Comment: @Zommuter, exactly!